# How can you run a memSQL admin command in Docker in a terminal line?

Tags: docker, singlestore

How can I run the following memSQL admin command in docker using the terminal in MacOs?

This is the code: memsql-admin list-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updated image was just released to allow you to use memsql-admin commands, so if you pull the latest image now you can run:

```
docker exec -it memsql-ciab memsql-admin list-nodes
```

The previous version of the docker-ciab you were running doesn't actually leverage toolbox to manage nodes in that image.  This is because for a single host, memsqlctl provides the same functionality with less complexity than toolbox.  So you can simply use the command `memsqlctl list-nodes` in the image to accomplish what you want, e.g.

```
docker exec -it memsql-ciab memsqlctl list-nodes
```

Comment: Excelent. Thank you! This worked perfectly as memsql-admin list-nodes returned empty